# HTML + JavaScript Date Setters funciton setting differnt date other than the input

Tags: javascript

Consider the following code of HTML & JavaScript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <script>
        var str = "20990229";
        var showDate = new Date();
        showDate.setFullYear(str.substring(0, 4))
        showDate.setMonth(parseInt(str.substring(4, 6), 10) - 1)
        showDate.setDate(str.substring(6, 8))
        document.write(showDate)
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Output**:

> Fri Mar 01 2099 16:02:52 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

The output is not the correct one, where I am going wrong is not known.

Could anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: What output did you expect?

Comment: 2099 will not be a leap year , so no 29 feb on 2099

Comment: new Date(2099, 1, 29) is March as there is no 29th Feb in 2099

Comment: Ohh my bad I forgot.. Randomly I gave a date and expected different answer than what it is showing..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output is exactly as it should be:

```
var str = "20990229";
var showDate = new Date();

showDate.setFullYear(str.substring(0, 4)); // Set year to 2099
showDate.setMonth(parseInt(str.substring(4, 6), 10) - 1); // Set month to 1
showDate.setDate(str.substring(6, 8)); // Set date to 29
```

That would be 29th February 2099. (Note that months are indexed from 0).

Since 2099 is not a leap year there is no February 29th, and the date corresponds to March 1st.

If you change the year to one that is a leap year (such as 2096) then the output will be as you expect. Here's [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/jamesallardice/9EtCW/).